# Python MySQLdb Programming Error: 1064 when inserting data

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I have this list

```
info=[[u' Rasta.eon 2 - 1 Rasta.Xd   ', u'Razer CS:GO Tournament 2', u'26-02-2014'], [u' XPC 1       - 2 WP.GG  ', u'Roccat DotA 2 Tournament', u'26-02-2014']]

conn= MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='',db='ee')

c = conn.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO todaysmatches (match,tournamentname,matchdate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
c.executemany(query, info)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

when I try to execute the query I get this error

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match,tournamentname,matchdate) VALUES \n(' Rasta.eon 2 - 1 Rasta.Xd   ','Razer C' at line 1")
```

match is varchar(150),tournamentname is varchar(150),matchdate is DATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` is a keyword in MySQL. You can use it as a column name if you backquote it

```
INSERT INTO todaysmatches (`match`,tournamentname,matchdate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
```

but it would be more convenient if you chose some other name for this column.

---

Look at what happens when you try to create a table with a column called `match`:

```
mysql> create table foo (match varchar(150), tournamentname varchar(150), matchdate DATE);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match varchar(150), tournamentname varchar(150), matchdate DATE)' at line 1
mysql> create table foo (`match` varchar(150), tournamentname varchar(150), matchdate DATE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Oh yes. `26-02-2014` should be `2014-02-26`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your fourth line to:

```
query = "INSERT INTO todaysmatches (`match`,`tournamentname`,`matchdate`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
```