# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to insert data into a MySQL database. I am using python 2.7 and I am using  the mysql.connector.

My error is:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (4200): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s) at line 1.

This indicates a error in my code where I attempt to insert my variable np (VALUES (%s)");). np is a "noun-phrase" such as a "skate board".

```
import mysql.connector
from textblob import TextBlob

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXX', password='XXX',
                              host='XXXXX',
                              database='XXXX')

cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

Latest = ("SELECT * FROM SentAnalysis")
cursor.execute(Latest)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    SentText = row[2]
    blob = TextBlob(SentText)
    for np in blob.noun_phrases:
        print(np)
        SQLInsertCmd = ("INSERT INTO TestNounPhrase (NPhrase) VALUES (%s)")
        cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd,np)

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

The example from the manual is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html. e.g.

```
 "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

I can't see a difference. This error is also discussed in detail here : [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064) Other similar examples on stackoverflow have been linked to [reserved words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226488/python-mysqldb-programming-error-1064-when-inserting-data), [Redundant comas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702026/programmingerror-1064) .But looking at these examples I can't spot an obvious error.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you only have a single entry for `VALUES` I believe you need a comma in your tuple: `VALUES (%s,)`.

Comment: I updated to include a comma and I still get the same error.

Comment: I speculate that the issue is at least partly due to that you are trying to select and insert at the same time.  Question upvoted +1.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid a select in this scenario? The select currently extracts the information required to run the "Noun Phrase" analysis . The output of this analysis is then inserted into another table. I have used select and inserts in the same script before without issue e.g.
 selecting data-> running sentiment analysis on the data-> then inserting the sentiment results into a new table.

Comment: The correct way to fix it is to convert the tuple which contains the value to insert into a 'full tuple'. e.g.:

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue here might be the semicolon at the end of the query.

Have a good day.

Comment: Struggled for hours, thought it was the prepared statement issue. But this was the problem.

Answer (score 8):

str parameter in SQL query must by in quote 'str'.
So, need use '%s' with ' ' for str, and %s without ' ' for numbers:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO db_name (str,int,str,int)
                  VALUES ('%s', %s, '%s', %s)""" % (str,int,str,int))
cnx.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert the tuple which contains the value to insert into a '*full tuple*'. 
e.g.:

```
for np in blob.noun_phrases:
        np=(np,)
```

In a generic example, if you just have one column to insert, it would be:

```
to_insert=('A value to insert',)
```

Lastly, if you had multiple values to insert at a time:

```
to_insert_multiple=[('value1',), ('value2',), ('valueN',)]
```

I hope it helps, it worked for me in *py3.7*

Comment: This is the correct answer - the _values_ argument to `cursor.execute` must be a _tuple_, and string formatting / concatenation solutions should be avoided due to the risk of quoting errors and SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SQLInsertCmd = """INSERT INTO
                  TestNounPhrase (NPhrase) VALUES ((%s))"""  % (np)
cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd)
```

Comment: This generates a new error that I can't find much information (in relation to 'word"):  "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError. Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'word' cannot be converted to a MySQL type".

Comment: What if you try, SQLInsertCmd = ("INSERT INTO TestNounPhrase (NPhrase) VALUES ((%s))")
        cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd,[np])

Comment: okay, not the most pythonic way but this ought to fix it, SQLInsertCmd = """INSERT INTO
      TestNounPhrase (NPhrase) VALUES ((%s))"""  % (np)
cursor.execute(SQLInsertCmd)

Comment: Error again...It still references a 1064 (42000) error,  but rather than saying  "near '%s" it says "near 'seymour'".  'seymour' is the result of the first iteration of the  loop (for np in blob.noun_phrases:) that extracts the "noun phrase" from the column "SentText".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151847/discussion-between-pritesh-and-steve).

Comment: full error:   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'seymour))' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late for this post but here is my solution for this.
I'm using py 3.10
I think this error comes because of using/passing string to cursor, to avoid this we can use tuple as pointed out by some answers above.

```
    from mysql import connector
    cnx = connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    YOUR_VALUES = (FIELD_NAME_1,FIELD_NAME_2,...)
    query = f"INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`FIELD_NAME_1`, `FIELD_NAME_2`) VALUES 
            {VAL}"
    cursor.execute(query)
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the single parameter statement, this worked:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO cust (user) VALUES(%s)" % (username))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error and while searching for its solution I stumbled upon this question after several attempts I was able to resolve. The mistake was a typing error for column name in `WHERE` clause of `UPDATE` statement. My column name was 'ROLL_NO' instead I had typed 'ROLL_NO.'
Please look to this point as well.

Answer (score 0):

when calling the `execute()` method:

```
  cursor.execute(query, (param))
```

should be:

```
  cursor.execute(query, (param,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite a struggle with this error because one of the column-name was `exit`. Be aware that database will accept this as a column name but when you try to insert from python, you need to cover the column in with backticks `

Answer (score 0):

you should give %s value like this:

```
"INSERT INTO LaptopPrice (Name) VALUES ('%s')" % value
```

if you have few values you have to use tuple of your valuse like this code:
"INSERT INTO LaptopPrice (Name, Price, Size, Weight, ScreenSize, Resolution, CPU, RAM, RAMType, Memory, MemoryType, GraphicCard) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % tuple(values)

Answer (score -2):

mycursor.execute("insert into table_name(column) values(%s)"%data_variable)

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem.