# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Tags: python, mysql

Am having problems with MySql not recognizing this syntax.

I think the issue is in the the exceute statement. I was using their previous method https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

```
def insertPS3(name,gamedb):
    mycursor = gamedb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO ps3 (name) VALUES (%s,)""" % (name,))
    gamedb.commit()
```

Edit

'%s' is the fix

Comment: Why is there a comma after `%s`?

Comment: I saw in another link that might help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665819/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1064-4200-you-have-an-error-in-your?rq=1>

Answer (score 3):

Instead of formatting the SQL statement using python string formatting you should let the cursor handle it for you. Passing a tuple of params as the second argument to `execute` (the same length as the number of `%s`s in the statement) will allow the cursor to perform the correct string formatting

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO ps3 (name) VALUES (%s)", (name,))
```

Comment: I fixed it I just need to do ```'%s'``` instead of ```%s``` by it self