# Syntax error but followed documentation, mysql Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to learn and build a program that communicates with a discord server, and a SQL server. I'm not familiar with SQL at all but know Python. I have looked through relevant Stackexchange posts,
[mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665819/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1064-4200-you-have-an-error-in-your) is the most relevant one.
I have version 3.8 Python with Conda interuptor, using the Pycharm IDE, and mysql verr 8.0.22. This is the documentation that I followed, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html
I get this error, I know where the error happens but have no idea why it's happening (syntax error).

```
  File "C:\Users\Chapm\GitHub\Pew-Pew\Main.py", line 52, in <module>
    cursor.execute(conn_query, profile_data)
  File "C:\Users\Chapm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\Chapm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 651, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\Chapm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 538, in _handle_result
  raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''User', 'Value', 'Wins', 'Losses')VALUES ('DamagedTwitch', 0.1667, 1, 5)' at line 1
```

This is the code I have for the program, any tips or advice is helpful too. Should I use an env file for the connection to the SQL too?

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode



def main():
    # connect to discord bot
    load_dotenv()
    # bot token.
    TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
    # discord server, insert method here to get servers; this is for future reference.
    guildName = os.getenv('SERVER_TOKEN')
    profiles = os.getenv('PROFILES')
    client = discord.Client()
    
    #insert mysql connections here

#this isn't empty in actually code, (obviously)
conn = None
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='',
    user='',
    password='',
    database='')
if conn.is_connected():
    print('Connected to MySQL database')
cursor = conn.cursor()

user = 'DamagedTwitch'
wins = 1
losses = 5
value = round(wins / (wins + losses), 4)

conn_cursor = conn.cursor()
conn_query = (
    "INSERT INTO Profile ('User', 'Value', 'Wins', 'Losses')"
    "VALUES (%(User)s, %(Value)s, %(Wins)s, %(Losses)s)")
profile_data = {
    'User': user,
    'Value': value,
    'Wins': wins,
    'Losses': losses,
}
cursor.execute(conn_query, profile_data)
conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

If you need to know how I created the table, this is the code for that.

````
def add_table(cursor):
    DB_NAME = 'PewPew'
    TABLES = {}

    TABLES['Profile'] = (
        "CREATE TABLE `Profile` ("
        "  `User` varchar(37) NOT NULL,"
        "  `Value` float(20) NOT NULL,"
        "  `Wins` int(11) NOT NULL,"
        "  `Losses` int(11) NOT NULL,"
        "  PRIMARY KEY (`User`)"
        ") ENGINE=InnoDB")

    for table_name in TABLES:
        table_description = TABLES[table_name]
        try:
            print("Creating table {}: ".format(table_name), end='')
            cursor.execute(table_description)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR:
                print("already exists.")
            else:
                print(err.msg)
        else:
            print("OK")

        try:
            cursor.execute(
                "CREATE DATABASE {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'".format(DB_NAME))
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))
            exit(1)
    ```
````

Comment: Field names souldn't be in `'`.

Comment: Field names should not be enclosed in quotes; if they need escaping use backticks `\``

Comment: Note that you did the right thing in your `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: Thank you guys, it's odd using back ticks. It was hard to tell the difference in the documentation.