# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000). The leads the SQL injection error, when fixed, it doesn't commit data correctly

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I looked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665819/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1064-4200-you-have-an-error-in-your) It fixes the error if the code is like:

```
"""INSERT IGNORE INTO analysing_tweet(created_at) VALUES (("%s"))""" % (tweeted_values["created_at"])
```

However, after talking to other people, about this error, people have said this practice is bad. So once I fixed it to like this:

```
query = """INSERT IGNORE INTO analysing_tweet(created_at) VALUES (("%s"))"""
values = (tweet_values["created_at"])
cursor.execute(query, values)
```

It executes with no problem, but in the database it adds `%s`, it looked like this

| created_at |
| --- |
| %s |

Versions:

MySQL: 8.0.25

Python: 3.8.10

mysql-connector: 2.2.9

mysql-connector-python: 8.0.25

Comment: It came to the same results. When cursor.execute is doesn't seem the change the %s. Also it comes back with the old error. "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1"

Comment: Tried it both way you suggested initial way it came the same error previously and now with "('%s')" it ass "%s" to the table

Comment: Should be `VALUES (%s)` -> no double quotes and no extra parentheses.  The second argument to `cursor.execute` should be a tuple, not a scalar.